# Postman = To assert that the array in the response body contains a string value in all its elements

Tags: postman

I'm new to Postman. My Postman is failing to match test criteria. Could anyone please help! It is returning true even if there is no match

```js
pm.test('Hourly metrics report generated to only 1 building', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.attributes, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.building_ref_id).to.include('Mounting_View-EN-1-Internal_Alpha')
    })
})
```

```json
    {
                "id": "423317",
                "type": "space",
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "RM_05_030",
                    "space_ref_id": "RM_05_030",
                    "building_ref_id": "80_Fen",
                    "floor_ref_id": "5"
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the code above is incomplete and that the response is actually and array of objects and that `jsonData` contains the parsed response body as a JavaScript array of objects.

The `_.each()` function takes an array as its first parameter, so you should not pass `jsonData.attributes`. This is the reason that your test passed; `jsonData.attributes` isn't an array, your callback will never get executed and no failing assertions means a succeeding test.

You can iterate over `jsonData` and assert that every item has a nested attribute `item.attributes.building_ref_id` containing your string:

```js
jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('Hourly metrics report generated to only 1 building', () => {
    _.each(jsonData, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.attributes.building_ref_id).to.include('Mounting_View-EN-1-Internal_Alpha')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It still didn't help me. I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"

Comment: Could you share your code? It sounds like the each loop is happening, but you're trying to access the `attributes` property of an object that is not an array item. I think it's not possible that an array item is `undefined` as JSON does not support `undefined` array items.

Comment: I'm using this code:var jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('Hourly metrics report generated to only 1 building', () => {
    _.each(jsonData, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.include[1].attributes.building_ref_id).to.include('Mounting_View-EN-1-Internal_Alpha')
    })
})

Comment: Why do you use `item.include[1]`? Based on your original question I think you should use `pm.expect(item.attributes.building_ref_id)...`. If that doesn't work I'm afraid I would need more information about the actual response's structure to be able to give you any more advice.